# Use texttt and non-italic characters in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

In my preamble:

```latex
\sisetup{detect-all}

\DeclareSIUnit\bin{b}
\DeclareSIUnit\hex{h}
```

And body:

```latex
\begin{aligned}
  \text{input} &= \SI[parse-numbers = false]{\texttt{01010110111000100001100110110010010001001011001111011011010000111000000100011110100111010011101010011110100001011111001101001111}}{\bin} \\
  &= \SI[parse-numbers = false]{56E219B244B3DB43811E9D3A9E85F34F}{\hex}
\end{aligned}
```

I used `parser-numbers = false` for both, but for different reasons. For the binary number, I want to use `\texttt`. For the hex number, I want to include alpha character.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to accomplish the `\texttt` for the binary number.

I considered `\texttt{01010110111000100001100110110010010001001011001111011011010000111000000100011110100111010011101010011110100001011111001101001111} \si{\bin}`, but would prefer wrapping in `\SI`.

2. The hex number renders, but alpha characters are italic. Is there any easily way to make them non-italic without `\text` (or similar) for each alpha character?

Answer (score 4):

With v3 you could do something like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\bin{b}
\DeclareSIUnit\hex{h}
\begin{document}

\[
  \sisetup{propagate-math-font}
  \begin{aligned}
    \text{input} &=
    \mathtt{
    \qty{01010110111000100001100110110010010001001011001111011011010000111000000100011110100111010011101010011110100001011111001101001111}{\bin}
    }\\
    &=
    \mathrm{
      \qty[input-digits = 01234567890ABCDEF, input-exponent-markers = ]{56E219B244B3DB43811E9D3A9E85F34F}{\hex}
    }
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

The idea here is to use `propagate-math-font` to apply `\mathrm` or `\mathtt` inside the numerical argument, so you get the effect you want. The number parser can easily be adjusted to handle hexidecimal input, as shown.

Comment: Dealing with leading zeros is the most tricky part: at the moment you'd have to set a minimum integer digit count. Perhaps one that needs a new option (`retain-leading-zeros` - if it's urgent I could add to the v3.1 list).